# Shell Bash script to print numbers in ascending order

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am really new to shell Bash scripting.  I need to print numbers in ascending order on a line for a given arbitrary number that is input by the user.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare nos[5]=(4 -1 2 66 10)
# Prints the number befor sorting

echo "Original Numbers in array:"
for (( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ))
    do
      echo ${nos[$i]}
    done

 #
 # Now do the Sorting of numbers  
 #

for (( i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++ ))
do
   for (( j = $i; j <= 4; j++ ))
   do
      if [ ${nos[$i]} -gt ${nos[$j]}  ]; then
       t=${nos[$i]}
       nos[$i]=${nos[$j]}
       nos[$j]=$t
      fi
   done
done

#
# Print the sorted number
# 
echo -e "\nSorted Numbers in Ascending Order:"
for (( i=0; i <= 4; i++ )) 
do
  echo ${nos[$i]}
done
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: I will paste what I have done, i don't know how to let user input arbitrary number so I am just asking them for how many integers they want to input and then store it in array

Comment: consider editing your question to include an example session of your problem, you only need 3-4 lines of output to illustrate the problem. You get code/output to line up nice and neat by indenting with 4 spaces or use the `{}` tool near the top left of the edit box. Good luck.

Comment: Why are you not using `sort` command?

Comment: Dont know what it is? And main issue is that I need to intake arbitrary input from the user and then sort it and display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=' ' read -ra arr -p "Enter numbers: "
Enter numbers: 4 -1 2 66 10

sort -n <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
-1
2
4
10
66
```

- `IFS=' '` to make `read` all number delimited by space
- 'read -ra` to read all numbers in an array
- `sort -n` to sort numbers numerically
- `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` to print each element of array in separate line
- `<(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")` is process substitution that make it `printf` command behave like a file for `sort -n` command.

Comment: wow this is really helpful, I changed the code and making it print in a line but how to space out the numbers in one line?

Comment: Just use: `sort -n <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}") | tr "\n" " "; echo`

Comment: Could you tel me one more thing, that is how can i put the condition to take in greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1000000

Comment: This answer was on how to accept numbers and sorting them. For restricting input numbers you need more code and I would suggest creating a different question for that to get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ask user to give input by comma and parse it and then populate the `nos` array..

```
echo "Please enter numbers separated by comma: "
read string_var
IFS=',' read -a nos <<< "$string_var"
```

Or by space it is more easy:

```
echo "Please enter numbers separated by space: "
read string_var
nos=($string_var)   //now you can access it like array...

// now rest of the code ....
```

Comment: I am not suppose to intake in numbers seperated by commas

Comment: it is an option...you can get each number followed by `enter` and populate the array..

Answer (score 1):

#### Bashisms, using bash

If you

- want to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only (no fork and no external binaries)
- use small interger numbers (smaller then 2^60 aka: < 2305843009213693952)
- have no duplicated numbers

Under 64 bit bash, you could use array index to store and sort your integer:

```
read -a array <<<'4 -1 2 66 10'
for i in ${array[@]};do
    sorted[i+(2<<60)]=''
  done
for i in ${!sorted[@]};do
    echo $[i-(2<<60)]
  done
-1
2
4
10
66
```

#### For dealing with duplicate:

```
read -a arr <<<'4 -1 2 66 -12 -10 10 2 24 -10'

for i in ${arr[@]};do
    ((srtd[i+(2<<60)]++))
  done

for i in ${!srtd[@]};do
    for ((l=0;l<${srtd[i]};l++));do
        echo $[i-(2<<60)]
      done
  done

-12
-10
-10
-1
2
2
4
10
24
66
```